# Modifying style on creating MFC modelless child dialog

Tags: c++, winapi, visual-c++, mfc

I am creating modelless child dialog.For achieveing tab order, while creating dialog I need to add [`DS_CONTROL` style](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff729172.aspx) programmatically.

I have overridden `PreSubClassWindow` and added the style but it is not working whereas If I set `DS_CONTROL` in resource properties, tab order is working fine.

As per my requirement (since I am creating custom dialog), I should not set in resource properties.

Please anyone help me to achieve my requirement.

Comment: [What is the DS_CONTROL style for?](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20040730-00/?p=38293)

Comment: @ChristopherOicles: You never use `CreateWindow` for modeless dialogs. You'd use [CreateDialogParam](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645445.aspx) and related API functions.

Comment: I was confused about `CreateWindow` but MFC modeless dialogs use the `Create` member function of your derived `CDialog` class.

Comment: Are you **really** creating a child dialog? Or is this an owned dialog?

Comment: I am creating a child dialog only.

Comment: If I use WS_EX_CONTROLPARENT instead of DS_CONTROL the tab order is working fine.

Comment: So you **aren't** creating a child dialog, but rather an **owned** dialog. This question is useless, if you don't get the terminology straight. See [window features](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632599.aspx) for mandatory reading.